# Liblinphone: получить картинку

Tags: ios, swift

Использую linphone в своем проекте и нужно вывести видео от входящего звонка. Как это сделать? Пытался через свойство `Core` присвоить вьюшку `nativeVideoWindow`, но в ней ничего не отображается. Свойства `videoDisplayEnabled` и `videoActivationPolicy.automaticallyAccept` тоже выставлены в `true`. Может, я что-то забыл еще включить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения проблемы необходимо обновлять параметры звонка, либо принимать его с обновленными параметрами. Только после этого видео начинает проигрываться в связанном с Core UIView:

```
if let currentCall = core?.currentCall, let callParams = try? core?.createCallParams(call: currentCall) {
    callParams.videoEnabled = true
    callParams.videoDirection = .RecvOnly
    do {
        try currentCall.acceptWithParams(params: callParams)
    } catch {
        print("accept call error")
        dump(error)
    }
}
```

`callParams.videoDirection = .RecvOnly` нужно для того, чтобы у приложения не запрашивался доступ к камере телефона.